# How to use LIKE in php query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I want to search a certain value that I get from a form and I think I have something wrong in my query.

code:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];

$sql="select news_text,news_no,title_of_the_new from news where news_text like %'$search'%";
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `%'$search'%` should be `'%$search%'`.  Also, you should escape that.  What if I search for `'; DROP TABLE news; -- `?

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) The percent signs need to go inside your single-quotes: so, `like '%$search%'"` instead of `like %'$search'%"`

2) You need to be using bind variables rather than directly interpolating the incoming `search` value into your query. You are exposing yourself to SQL injection attacks with this method. So, `like '?'`, followed by a `bind`, with the parameter value equal to `'%' + $search + '%'`

Comment: 2) is incorrect. The query should be like '?' and the string passed by bind needs a % either side.

Comment: Thank you for the catch, @PeteR. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$search = $_POST['search'];

$sql="select news_text,news_no,title_of_the_new from news where news_text like '%$search%'";
```

Comment: $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searh']);